# Select Years with the Greatest Number of Repeatedly Sampled Sites in R

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I have many sites that were sampled over many "Season-Year" combinations (time column). I want to select Season-Year combinations that have 10 or more of the same sites. Data is at the bottom of this post. Any thoughts for making this work?

Code I have tried that didn't work:

```
subset1 <- tbl_df(coords) %>%
  group_by(SznYr) %>%
  tally(SiteID) %>%
  top_n(10)

subset2 <- tbl_df(coords) %>% group_by(SznYr) %>% top_n(2, SiteID)
```

The data is in this googledoc link -- https://docs.google.com/document/d/1SsTIZwJBGGqeaz7VyH7lh9mLc8XQJ4b9gEnQ_3hWzj4/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

We can use `count` and then filter for `n >= 10`. However, as you can see in the following, the maximum count number is only 3. I don't think you can find a `SznYr` with 10 or more than 10 counts.

```
coords %>%
  count(SITEID, SznYr) %>%
  arrange(desc(n))
# # A tibble: 2,013 x 3
#    SITEID SznYr           n
#    <fct>  <fct>       <int>
#  1 SB506  1994-Summer     3
#  2 SB506  1995-Summer     3
#  3 SB506  1996-Spring     3
#  4 SB267  1994-Fall       2
#  5 SB267  1995-Winter     2
#  6 SB357  1995-Summer     2
#  7 SB367  1995-Summer     2
#  8 SB368  1994-Fall       2
#  9 SB368  1995-Fall       2
# 10 SB407  1993-Winter     2
# # ... with 2,003 more rows
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! However, this doesn't look like it does what I was hoping it would do. Should I clarify?

Comment: Yes, please clarify.

Comment: I believe this answers the question asked.